# Visualize multiple rejection reasons

Tags: python, data-visualization, matplotlib, heatmap

> **Goal**: Visualize why loans are rejected which can be due to multiple reasons. A loan is either rejected or accepted. Any rejection
>   is caused by one or more rejection reasons. There is a list of
>   rejection reasons which has about 20 entries. The viewer must
>   understand that
>
> 1. loans are often rejected by multiple reasons and
> 2. which are the most prevalent reasons.
>
> more than one chart. I also thought of small multiples.This can be achieved in one chart or

**What is a good way of visualizing this?**

That's how I tried to visualize it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def explode_reasons(reasons):
    all_reasons = [f'reason_{i}' for i in range(20)]
    tmp = {x: x in reasons for x in all_reasons}
    return pd.Series(tmp)

df = pd.concat([df, df['reasons'].apply(explode_reasons)], axis=1)

reason_cols = [f'reason_{i}' for i in range(20)]
sns.heatmap(~df.loc[:, reason_cols].sort_values(reason_cols, ascending=False), cbar=False)
```

[image]

That's how my data looks like.

```
|   id | rejected   | reasons                                 |
|-----:|:-----------|:----------------------------------------| 
|    0 | False      | []                                      | 
|    1 | False      | []                                      | 
|    2 | False      | []                                      | 
|    3 | True       | ['reason_18', 'reason_10', 'reason_13'] | 
|    4 | True       | ['reason_15', 'reason_8', 'reason_2']   |
```

That's how it can be reproduced

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(100),
                'rejected': random.choices([True, False], weights=[80, 20], k=100)})

def generate_rejections(rejected):
    if not rejected:
        return []

    reasons = random.choices([f'reason_{i}' for i in range(20)], 
                            weights=range(1, 21), 
                            k=random.randint(1, 5))
    return list(set(reasons))

df['reasons'] = df['rejected'].apply(generate_rejections)
```

Comment: For goal 2 a [classification tree](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/widm.8) might be something to play with? Doesn't visualise the most prevalent reasons per se, but it does illustrate the explanatory power of some over others.

Comment: Another suggestion for the second goal, why don't you try to plot histogram with the different reasons. This should give clients a good overview of the most contributing factors to loans being rejected @PalimPalim

Comment: Thanks!!! @Stochastic

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset for people to work with?

Comment: My guess is several plots, to illustrate different aspects of what's going on, would be appropriate.